# Why form is not valid in django

Tags: python, django, forms, python-3.x

## Why form is not valid in django!

hi
i dont know why my form is not valid!
i tried this

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=35)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=35)
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(required=True, min_length=8, max_length=64)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(required=True, min_length=8, max_length=64)
```

template.html

```
<form id="signupForm" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
            <input id="first_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="firstname" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
            <input id="last_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="lastname" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name"  />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="username" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Choose Username" />
    <input id="email" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="email" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Your Email" />
    <input id="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" />
    <input id="confirm_password" type="password" name="confirm_password" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <div class="topmargin active">
        <div class="row" style="display: flex;">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
                <label>I'm </label>
                <select name="month" class = "form-control input-lg">
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br />
            <span class="help-block">By clicking Create my account, you agree to our Terms and that you have read our Data Use Policy, including our Cookie Use.</span>
    <button class="btn btn-block signup-btn" type="submit">Create my account</button>
</form>
```

i think it's because i dont pass the form to template, but i dont wanna do that!
it mixes the responsive style
commands are welcome
thank you

Comment: There is no form rendering. You should have.

Comment: How do you know it is not valid?  What's the error?  And, yes, it is easier including the form in the template.

Comment: all i know is just form.is_valid() returns False @jgmh

Comment: Ok. I'd start by printing the `request.POST` in the `views.py` before the validation.  That should show you the errors.  By the way, shouldn't it be `name="first_name"` instead of `name="firstname"` in order to pass the form to the ``views.py`?

Comment: @jgmh i think names doesn't matter! all matters is names should be the same when passing to the form!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problems are here:

```
<input id="first_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="firstname" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" />

<input id="last_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="lastname" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name"  />
```

In your form you use **first_name** and **last_name** with underscore, but on input they are without the underscore.

You need to change the input names to match the form fields:

```
<input id="first_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="first_name" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="First Name" />

<input id="last_name" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="last_name" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Last Name"  />
```

Comment: **yup, you are right, that was the problem, thank you**